# How to create a ranking in power bi matrix with DAX from a single table with aggregation

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, rank

I'm trying to have a ranking of the supplier based on their cases sold from the last 12 months (MAT12_cs) in a matrix in Power BI.

Here is a sample data:

Table_sales

```
Supplier,   Product,    Account,    Rep,    MAT12_cs
Sup1,   Prod1,  Acc1,   Rep1,   56
Sup1,   Prod1,  Acc2,   Rep2,   45
Sup1,   Prod2,  Acc1,   Rep1,   43
Sup1,   Prod2,  Acc2,   Rep2,   66
Sup2,   Prod3,  Acc1,   Rep1,   15
Sup2,   Prod4,  Acc3,   Rep2,   104
Sup3,   Prod5,  Acc4,   Rep3,   86
Sup3,   Prod5,  Acc1,   Rep1,   80
```

Here is the result I'm expecting:

```
Supplier,   MAT12_cs,   Rank
Sup1,   210,    1
Sup3,   166,    2
Sup2,   119,    3
Total,  495
```

I tried RANKX in a measure:

```
Rank = RANKX(Table_sales,SUM(MAT12_CS))
```

It gives 1 everywhere.

I tried something like this but something is missing to make it work I think:

```
Rank = 
VAR ProdSales = SUM('Table_sales'[MAT12_cs])
VAR tblSales =
    SUMMARIZE (
        'Table_sales',
        'Table_sales'[Supplier],
        "Total Sales", SUM ( 'Table_sales'[MAT12_cs] )
    )
RETURN
    IF(ProdSales>0,COUNTROWS(FILTER(tblSales,[Total Sales]>ProdSales))+1,BLANK())
```

This gives me totals I don't by what I should replace countrows with to have a ranking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a measure (I am calling your table "Sales" for short):

```
Total Sale = SUM ( Sales[MAT12_cs] )
```

Create another measure:

```
Sale Rank =
IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( Sales[Supplier] ),
    RANKX ( ALL ( Sales[Supplier] ), [Total Sale] )
)
```

Put these measures into a matrix or table against suppliers. Result:

[image]

Explanation:

You must use ALL(Table) instead of just 'Table' in RANKX. Without ALL, RANKX will not see the entire data (as it must, to rank all sales), it will only see **filtered** table. For example, in the first row, you will only see sales for supplier 1, because your table "Sales" is filtered in this row by Sup1. As a result, RANKX is ranking just one record, that's why you are getting 1s in each line. When we use ALL, RANKX will (correctly) see all data.

After getting access to all suppliers, RANKX iterates them one by one, and for each supplier calculates their sales and then ranks them.

HASONEVALUE part is needed to remove ranking from the totals.

Comment: Overall it works.
It was wasn't working when I had multiple field as row in my matrix but if I keep only the field on which I did the ranking on it works!
Thanks a lot for thanking the time to reply to my post!